# Django: Uploaded files not being garbage collected, causing memory problems

Tags: python, django, memory, file-upload, heroku

I have a Django view which handles uploaded files, and when it is called repeatedly, we always encounter over memory errors. (We're on Heroku, so we get 512mb of memory per web dyno).

The over memory errors show that each call increases memory usage by the size of the file, and memory usage never goes back down.  I think the server reads the image into memory to save it into a Django model, but then never releases the memory when it's done.

I think there must be a reference to the image that is persisting after the function returns, preventing the image from being garbage collected.  But I can't think of what that could be.

Here's a simplified version of the code, which I tested to make sure it has the same problem:

```
def simplified_add_image(request, biz_id):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # the file is stored raw in the request
        newBI = NewBusinessImage(business_id=biz_id, name=request.GET.get("name"), primary_image=True)
        newBI.id = uuid.uuid4()
        newBI.save()
        uniquename = biz_id + ".." + get_a_uuid() + ".jpg"

        newBI.original_image.save(uniquename, ContentFile(request.read()))

        # this starts a series of tasks to process the image into various sizes.
        # don't think it's the problem because it runs on a separate server, and the
        # web server is the one that goes over memory
        tasks.image_meta_task.delay(uniquename, newBI.id)

        return StockJSONResponse(request, {
            "success" : True,
        })
```

I'd really appreciate any help.  Thanks a lot!

Clay

**The following is additional information that was requested in comments:**

We are storing our files on AmazonS3:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
from S3 import CallingFormat
AWS_CALLING_FORMAT = CallingFormat.SUBDOMAIN
```

And here is the NewBusinessImage model

```
class NewBusinessImage(models.Model):
    id = UUIDField(auto=True,primary_key=True,version=4, default=uuid.uuid4())
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/originals/')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/thumbnails/')
    display_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/displays/')
    enlarged_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/enlarged/')
    num_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
    primary_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: What's this `image_meta_task.delay`?

Comment: It's an asynchronous Celery task, which launches on a separate server (not my web server), to process the image into standard sizes and save them.

Comment: If this is a simplified version, that means that if you drop `image_meta_task.delay` you don't have memory problems? Also, where do you store files? Can you post settings.py storege settings and `NewBusinessImage` ?

Comment: @danihp Added the information you requested.  To be honest, I did not test this function without the image_meta_task.delay, because that task is required to keep our database sane.  I figured because it executes on a different server it was safe to leave in, even for the simplified version.  Do you think it could be involved/part of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to set newBI to None after newBI.save() ? Sorry, this only should free half of memory because request also has the image bytes ...

Comment: @ClayWardell Hi Clay, did you ever solve this issue? I'm having the same problem with non-freed memory for multiple file uploads on Django and also using S3 and doing some pre-processing on the file before saving.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django documentation it ships with 2 file upload handlers. The Memory and Temporary file handlers ([Link to docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers)

If you configure the setting [FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#file-upload-handlers) settings to only include "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler" it should never save the file to memory and technically never cause the memory issues you're facing at the moment.

Another option would be to set the [FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE) to a small amount that will cause the upload to go directly to disk.